# A question about joint measurability

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f(x,y): \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous in $x$ for fixed $y$, while being Borel measurable in $y$ for fixed $x$. Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an interval. I want to claim that the set of $x$ such that $f(x,y)$ belongs to $I$ for infinitely many $y$ is measurable.  Similarly, I want to claim that the set of $y$ such that $f(x,y)$ belongs to $I$ for infinitely many $x$ is measurable.

This is not homework. It seems like these two statements should be true, though I've no idea how to prove them.